# Where to put log files for tempdb?

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

In my current project we came up with a question where to put log file for tempdb.
Usually we put data file and log file on a dedicated drive in folder like t:\tempdb.

On one server we have tempdb logs that were put in the log folder for user user databases.

Is there any best practice on where to put log file for temp db?

Is it bad or good to keep it together with tempdb data file or with user log files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any best practice on where to put log file for temp db?

I dont think there is as such any best practice to put the log files. You may put it as per your space availability and system configuration.

> Is it bad or good to keep it together with tempdb data file or with
>   user log files?

No it is not bad but generally people keep it seperately.

But definitely you may check [SQL Server tempdb best practices increase performance](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/SQL-Server-tempdb-best-practices-increase-performance)

Comment: I think these are reasonable answers. Thank you for the performance link.